# Append new row to Excel file with PHPExcel

Tags: php, excel-2007, addition

I have this code

```
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    $LastRow = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getHighestRow();
    $row = $LastRow + 1;

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$row, $_POST['name']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B'.$row, $_POST['email'] );
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C'.$row, $_POST['tel']);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D'.$row, $_POST['adresss']);

    $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);

    $objWriter->save('files\Clientes.xlsx');
```

The problem in here is the always create a new .xlsx file or erase the others rows that are in Excel File, i need Add a new row...
Any ideas ?

Comment: Potential duplicate question of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11416934/adding-a-new-row-with-phpexcel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("FILE.xlsx");
$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
```

Just open the file

Answer (score 1):

In your current code you are creating a new PHPExcel() object each time. You need to load the existing, then insert a new row. See here for how: [Adding a new row with PHPExcel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11416934/phpexcel-add-new-line)