# One row to many is added PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have a script that inputs form data on a row in an excel file. Each time the form is sent the new data is appended to the same excel file.

The problem is that the new data is appended by two rows. So a blank row is inserted between each row.

Here is the code. $data contains the $_POST data.

```
function generateExcel($data) {
    $filename = dirname(__FILE__).'/myexcelfile.xlsx';

    // this is shortened
    $columns = array(
        'fieldname1' => 'Column 1', 
        'fieldname2' => 'Column 2', 
    );

    // check if file exist
    if(file_exists($filename)) {

        // load existing excel file
        $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($filename);

    } else {

        // Create new PHPExcel object
        $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
        $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

        $objWorksheet->insertNewRowBefore(1, 1);

        // Set column names
        $columnIndex = 0;
        foreach($columns as $columnName) {
            $objWorksheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($columnIndex, 1, $columnName);
            $columnIndex++;
        }
    }

    // get sheet and highest row
    $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
    $numberOfRows = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestRow();

    // Insert a new row after highest row
    $objWorksheet->insertNewRowBefore($numberOfRows + 1, 1);

    // Get the highest row again (should be one more since last time)
    // $numberOfRows2 = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestRow();

    // Insert data for each column
    $columnIndex = 0;
    foreach($columns as $fieldName => $columnName) {
        $fieldValue = $data[$fieldName];

        $objWorksheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($columnIndex, $numberOfRows + 1, $fieldValue);

        $columnIndex++;
    }

    // Save Excel 2007 file
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
    $objWriter->save($filename);
}
```

This is what I used:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12417477

[image: http://i.imgur.com/eYIIktZ.png]

Comment: You don't need to insertNewRowBefore(), that's probably causing your problem

Comment: @MarkBaker It doesn't seem to solve it. First form data was added on row 2 (as it should) but second input was added on row 4 and the next was added on row 6.

Comment: Note also that getHighestRow() isn't changed by inserting new rows.... it's purely the highest row value at load time.

Comment: Try some basic debugging, checking the row numbers returned by getHighestRow()  at each stage.... it's not impossible that there's a bug in PHPExcel itself, but I do spend several hours each day tracking down non-existent bugs

Comment: Ok. Even thou getHighestRow() only gets number of rows on first load I can't see why it should not work.

Comment: It seems like the error is somewhere else. It's like everything run twice. But if i just do echo 'test'; it's only printed once....

Answer (score 0):

I just guess that, can we try this

```
$objWorksheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($columnIndex,"",$columnName);
```

instead of

```
$objWorksheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($columnIndex, 1, $columnName);
```

Comment: That just generates an error since the method looks like this: setCellValueByColumnAndRow(columnindex, rowindex, cellvalue);