# How to update the values to excelsheet

Tags: php, html, phpexcel

I am trying to develop one HTML form which should update excel sheet in back end.
i created HTML page, below script

```
<html>
<tiltle>Status Tracking System</title>

</html>

<form action="xcel.php" method="POST"> 
    <label for="search"><FONT color=black>Enter Sample Number</label>
    </br>
    <input type="varchar" id="SO_ID" name="SO_ID" required/>

<select name="select">
<option value="Just_arrived">Just arrived</option>
<option value="Process_started ">Process started </option>
<option value="Analysis_started">Analysis started</option>
 <option value=" Delivered"> Delivered</option>
</select>
    </br>

<button>

   UPDATE
  </button>
</form>
```

I want to update data which user entered(Sample name and status) in form to excel sheet.
I have saved excel sheet as"asheet.xls", help me to connect these and do so.

Below is the PHP script saved in "xcel.php"

```
$SO_ID=$_POST['so'];
$Status=$_POST['status'];

require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';
require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
$inputFileName = 'asheet.xlsx';
$inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', $SO_ID);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B1', $Status);

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save("/var/www/html/apps/asheet.xlsx");
?>
```

any further information required feel free to reply.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Your html is a mess dude.. :/

Comment: what info u needed dude??

Comment: It's not a question nor request. I'm actually trying to give you some advice. * Your HTML code isn't clean. You might think, why is this advice? Because working organized and clean might be the most important things when it comes to programming.

Comment: Mark Baker maybe will later see this question (which should be tagget as phpexcel anyway), but I'm pretty sure that the PHPExcel library **doesn't** support .ods files for **writing**: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel  That said, are you sure you are passing the indexes properly? the phpexcel code is "fine", reader apart. Also, you are never submitting the form.

Comment: Thank u @briosheje, if possible can u edit the code ? i partially understands u r comment

Comment: `.ods` files are supported using the `OOCalc` Reader and the `OpenDocument` Writer, a naming discrepancy that still haunts me

Comment: But if you want to save as `asheet.xls` then you want the Excel5 Writer

Answer (score 0):

check this first
[Append new row to excel file using phpExcel library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16514447/append-new-row-to-excel-file-using-phpexcel-library)

Download phpExcel library from here
https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use stuff like [this](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/). But why not convert to csv instead?

Comment: i need php script sir