# PHPExcel: How to use insertNewRowBefore function correctly?

Tags: php, function, phpexcel

I want to add $x rows after line number $insert_here.

This is the function:

```
// Get the Excel file I want to work on:  
function get_excel_file(){

    // Need to define this to change a global variable inside a function
    global $objPHPExcel; 

    // Define an Exel Object to read files from: 
    $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('keywords.xlsx');

}


// Inserts new rows: Gets the number of rows to insers them before the second variable
function insert_rows( $objPHPExcel, $insert_here, $num_rows  ){ 

    echo $num_rows, $insert_here;

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->insertNewRowBefore( $insert_here, $num_rows ); 

}
```

When calling the function, I get a good echo of the variables. So I'm sure it's not from the variables.

What can be the problem? The Excel file looks exactly the same with no new lines inserted.

Comment: Are you saving the file again afterwards? I hate to ask such a stupid question, but a surprising number of people assume that PHPExcel is directly editing the loaded file saving everything you do automatically..... which isn't the case

Comment: Actually no. I didn't know i have to save.

Comment: You do need to save, in the same way that you'd need to save any changes in MS Excel itself, otherwise all you're doing is modifying the "in-memory" model for the duration of the request

Comment: Thanks mate. 
I'm having trouble saving too. 
In your spare time if you can take a look :) 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32317742/phpexcel-how-to-save-the-loaded-file-after-changes-has-made-on-it

Comment: It's pretty straightforward to save the file, most of the examples do it: `$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('filename.xlsx');`