# PHPExcel: How to save the loaded file after changes has made on it?

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have made some changes on a file using PHP and realized nothing was changes after running the code (with no any errors).

I understood that I have to save the file right after I change stuff in it.

When using the 'save' function, I get:

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Call to undefined method PHPExcel_Worksheet::save() in C:\wamp\www\PHPExcel\excel_fun.php on line 32

this is my function and the way I am calling it:

```
function save_file(){

    global $objPHPExcel;

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->save('keywords.xlsx');

}
save_file();
```

I tried using 
`$objPHPExcel->save('keywords.xlsx');` too without any success

get the same error:

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Call to undefined method PHPExcel::save() in C:\wamp\www\PHPExcel\excel_fun.php on line 32

so what *is* the right way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward to save the file, most of the examples do it.

You don't save the individual worksheet (you don't save individual worksheets in MS Excel either), you save the whole spreadsheet (PHPExcel object):

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('keywords.xlsx');
```

Comment: I just didn't understand why I need to use `createWriter` and save it as a new object and not use the same object variable.

Comment: Because that was a design decision when the library was first written, making it easy to work with different writer objects to handle each of the different file formats that are supported

Comment: Ok. Cool, Thanks. 
Yes, I saw a lot of examples like this but I didn't know this is mandatory to work this way..